# MySQL8 Server is Missing from `launchctl list`

Tags: macos-catalina, macports, launchd, mysql-8.0

I installed MySQL 8 from MacPorts on macOS 10.15 Catalina and started it up. I'm able to login using `mysql` command, and make changes to the databases.

But now I want to stop it and switch to the installation on my virtual machine. I've already setup NAT port forwarding in VirtualBox, but I'm not sure how I can stop MySQL server as I can't find it from the `launchctl list` listing.

The service is installed though, as a symbolic link in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql8-server.plist` pointing to the MacPorts directory tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Did you try `sudo`?

You can unload the MySQL8-Server service using the `port` command from MacPorts like this: `port unload mysql8-server`. It requires root priviledge.

Also, MySQL server is running in as its own user - `_mysql`, so listing it in `launchctl list` requires running the command with root priviledge as well.

Comment: `launchctl list` will list launch **agents** in your user session. `sudo launchctl list` will list launch **daemons** loaded in the system/root context.